# Decorator exception-handler is not catching exceptions raised by a generator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, generator, decorator

I tried to implement a decorator exception handler to try and dry the exception handling statements in my module:

```
def exception_delegator(operation):
    @wraps(operation)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        try:
            return operation(*args, **kwargs)
        except (ClientError, ConnectTimeoutError, ReadTimeoutError) as e:
            raise MyCustomException(
                None,
                original_exception=e,
                traceback=True,
                operation_desc=self.operation_desc,
                resource_desc=self.resource_desc,
            )
        except MyCustomException:
            raise MyCustomException(
                None,
                operation_desc=self.operation_desc,
                resource_desc=self.resource_desc,
            )

    return wrapper
```

The handler works perfectly fine except when it comes to a generator method such as:

```
    @exception_delegator
    def list_objects(self):
        paginator = self.client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
        iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=self.bucket, Prefix=self.prefix)
        for response in iterator:
            yield response
```

I was simply expecting the exceptions raised from within the generator method to be caught by the exception handler decorator, instead, exceptions raised from within the generator are not caught and do propagate up the call-stack. The reason I believe that this is due to the wrapped method being a generator is because, it works with normal functions and methods, and it works when I implement the exception handling in the generator method itself.

Here is an abstract example:

```
def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError:
            raise MyCustomException
    return wrapper


class MyCustomException(Exception):
    pass

def iterator():
    for i in range(4):
        if i == 3:
            raise ValueError
        print(i)
        yield i

@decorator
def gen():
    for i in iterator():
        yield i

results = list(gen())
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21476\3739375099.py in <cell line: 26>()
     24         yield i
     25 
---> 26 results = list(gen())

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21476\3739375099.py in gen()
     21 @decorator
     22 def gen():
---> 23     for i in iterator():
     24         yield i
     25 

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21476\3739375099.py in iterator()
     15     for i in range(4):
     16         if i == 3:
---> 17             raise ValueError
     18         print(i)
     19         yield i

ValueError:
```

What am I missing here, how can I handle the generator correctly in this case?

Comment: No, because `return operation(*args, **kwargs)` will not raise any exceptions *because the generator won't even start executing yet!*

Comment: What you are missing here is that `g = gen()` doesn't raise the exception, but `list(g)` *does*

Comment: Also, your decorator returns a regular function whether it decorates a regular function or a generator function. It's not trivial for the decorator to detect which it is decorating. (If it decorates a generator function, it should probably use `yield from operation(...)` rather than `return operation(...)`).

Comment: (Even then, you may want to raise your custom exception on each call to `next`, rather than having an exception abort the iteration of the original generator.)

Comment: @chepner well, you can use `inspect.isgeneratorfunction`, but you'd have to return a different type of wrapper depending

Comment: Thanks guys, your comments alongside the link that was suggested, answer my questions.
[Can you write a python decorator that works for generator functions and normal functions, and matches their return styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622473/can-you-write-a-python-decorator-that-works-for-generator-functions-and-normal-f)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, that's part of what I lump under "nontrivial" :)